# Python: Length of list as single integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to output the length of a list as a single integer, eg:

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'] 
len(l1) = 3
```

However, it is printing on cmdline with 1s down the page, eg:
1
1
1
1
1
1
etc

How can I get it to just output the number rather than a list of 1s?

(Here's the code:)

```
def Q3():
  from datetime import datetime, timedelta 
  inputauth = open("auth.log", "r") 
  authStrings = inputauth.readlines() 

  failedPass = 'Failed password for'
  for line in authStrings:
    time = line[7:15]
    dateHour = line[0:9]
    countAttack1 = []

    if time in line and failedPass in line:
      if dateHour == 'Feb  3 08':
        countAttack1.append(time)
        length1 = len(countAttack1)
        print(length1)
```

Ideally, I'd like it to output the number in a print so that I could format it, aka:

```
print("Attack 1: " + length1)
```

Comment: How is countAttack1 created? - Also the code is malformed. `len(list)`  should work just fine - so the error must be in that you are not actually creating a list.

Comment: It's a variable outside of the if statement - countAttack1 = [] - how would I check if I'm making a list? What would I look for to check?

Comment: Show the FULL code, complete from where you create countattack1, and the loop which needs to be somewhere (otherwise you won't see 1 1 1 1, ignoring recursion atm). The full function starting with `def ...`

Comment: Okay, I've edited it to show the full code - I don't know where the indents should/shouldn't be, because I realise now that it's caught in a loop and that's why it won't work but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as Syed Abdul Wahab said, the problem is that the "list" is getting recreated each loop. This makes so that the print reports "1", as it is the actual length of the list.
The other problem, repetition of the printng is similar - you are actually printing "each time in the loop".

The solution is then simple: you initialize the list outside the loop; and also report outside the loop.

```
def Q3():
  from datetime import datetime, timedelta 
  inputauth = open("auth.log", "r") 
  authStrings = inputauth.readlines() 

  failedPass = 'Failed password for'
  countAttack1 = []  # after this line the countAttack will be empty
  for line in authStrings:
    time = line[7:15]
    dateHour = line[0:9]

    if time in line and failedPass in line:
      if dateHour == 'Feb  3 08':
        countAttack1.append(time)

  length1 = len(countAttack1)
  print("Attack 1: " + str(length1))
```

I'd also like to take a bit of time to link you to [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) While the documentation is complex it will make printing much easier, above print is trnasformed into:

```
print("Attack 1: {0}".format(length1))
```

---

Further analysing the code gives some peculiarities, you check if `time` is in the `line` string. - However just a few codelines above you create `time` from a slice of `line` - so it will always be inside `line`. (Except for the edge case where line is not of correct length, but that'll error anyways). So that if statement should be simplified to:

```
    if failedPass in line:
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it, I'll have a look through the link you posted too, thank you!

Comment: @Lou ignore the top part and scroll down to the example there, it's much easier to just learn it by example.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looping and ifs are inside a loop. If so, just print the length outside loop scope.
Please share the complete code for a better answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function  that prints the  the length:

```
def print_length():
    if time in line and failedPass in line:    
        if dateHour == 'Feb  3 08':
           countAttack1.append(time)
    length1 = len(countAttack1)
    print(length1)
print_length()
>>>Print length of the List.
```